# Quick overview of cross-platform mobile development

Tags: mobile

I don't know the first thing about mobile application development.  I'm starting my research now.

Can someone give me a quick overview of the top most popular, mature and cross-platform technologies for creating and running applications that work on iphones, blackberries, windows mobiles and androids?  For example, let's say I want to create a mobile software application that monitors your heart rate and blood pressure via a piece of hardware connected to one of the mobile's port, and I want this to work on iphone, blackberry, windows mobile and android.

What development platforms should I consider?  What are the pros vs. cons of them?  How popular are they?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Phonegap](http://www.phonegap.com) might be what you're looking for. Basically you'll build a web-app that is local on the device and has access to JavaScript libraries which provide access to many of the device's OS APIs.

From their site:

> What is PhoneGap?
>   PhoneGap is an open
>   source development framework for
>   building cross-platform mobile apps.
>   Build apps in HTML and JavaScript and
>   still take advantage of core features
>   in iPhone/iTouch, iPad, Google
>   Android, Palm, Symbian and Blackberry
>   SDKs.SDKs.

Answer (score 1):

PhoneGap & Titanium are my favourites. Using them with Web Services in backend works the best. A good design article is at http://dotqsolutionsllc.wordpress.com/2011/01/13/iphone-android-blackberry-development-usa/

Comment: Lone link is [considered a poor answer](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion) since it is meaningless by itself and target resource is not guaranteed to be alive in the future. [It would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Platform will be dependent on the mobile phone you want to run that application. There are many other things apart from the port. These things are defined by the platform architecture. It includes event handling, UI, and much more.

You need to also test your application independently on each of these targets.

However you can make a web-application and have users use it via the mobile browser. This in some way can be said generic. It will work on all mobile browser's provided you follow the standards supported.

Answer (score 0):

[Developing cross platform mobile application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3369413/what-is-the-common-things-across-mobile-platform)