# Universal App development

Tags: android, ios, windows-phone

Is there any way (or platform) that allows to develop for all Major Plattforms (And,IOS,WP) in a unified way? I already took a look at Sencha, and it seams like a reasonable idea, but im currently working on a bigger Project and i don't think Javascript is suited for that.

I already know that only Android uses Java and that it doesn't run on WP or iOS, but is there maybe some other way than Web based?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Developing cross platform mobile application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3369413/developing-cross-platform-mobile-application)

Comment: O.P.: you can make your point even more effectively without using cuss words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a new responsibility for android, iOS and OSX in the new Delphi XE5.
It's based on a framework called [Firemonkey](http://www.embarcadero.com/products/rad-studio/fm-application-platform). The advantage is that you have to code only once, disadvantage is that you can only use those parts of the SDK that are the same on every platform.

There are also rumors that the next platform that is added to Delphi could be WP.
Unfortunately, this solution is not really cheap and opinions differ if it's all working or not. But there's a [30-day Trialversion](http://www.embarcadero.com/products/rad-studio/downloads) for tests.