# What are better HTML5 cross platform mobile app development alternatives?

Tags: android, jquery, html, cordova

I have been using Phonegap with JqueryMobile but for some reason I have felt that JqueryMobile is bulky and slower with Phonegap. Sometimes it does not give the expected performance from the app. I would like to know apart from Phonegap and JqueryMobile what are the other HTML5 and Jquery/or whatever based cross platform mobile app development alternatives?

Comment: Your question is off topic, because it doesn't have a single answer. But to give you another one, try Sencha Touch.

Comment: Also look at https://trigger.io/

Answer (score 1):

Alternative to phonegap:

1. Titanium
2. Sencha Touch

See more here:
[mobile application development framework](http://skytechgeek.com/2011/09/10-mobile-application-frameworks-for-easy-development/)

Also go through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3369413/developing-cross-platform-mobile-application?rq=1) link