# How to make cross platform mobile apps?

Tags: android, ios

I know slightly about android apps development using JAVA. And I also know that for IOS- Objective C is used.

But I can see in different places that their requirement is cross platform applications for mobile devices. How is that possible?

Comment: You may want to check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3369413/developing-cross-platform-mobile-application?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's 2 common ways to do it

1)HTML and javascript.  The advantage is it will run on anything with a good web browser.  The disadvantage is horrible performance, limited access to special OS features, UIs limited to web interfaces, browser specific bugs, and having to write javascript (really, I'd rather have a door slammed on my fingers).

2)C or C++ for business logic with UIs and glue code written for the platform.  Advantage is it will run anywhere from embedded devices to phones to PCs to supercomputers, and will be lightning fast.  Disadvantage is that it will require slightly better, higher paid programmers and may take a bit more time to write.

3)There's a few efforts at other languages like Xamarin for C#.  Its likely in between the 2 above in performance, and will otherwise have advantages similar to 2, with the added disadvantage or not being supported and more likely to break badly on new releases.