# Deploying HTML 5 mobile web apps

Tags: android, iphone, html, mobile

I apologise now if this turns out to be a stupid question, but I have read countless tutorials, and searched many times (maybe using the wrong terminology) but how do you install a Html 5 web app on a phone?

I've downloaded ones to my phone in the past, that were via web links, all I have found is people to pay who will convert it into various 'native' installs via the various stores, App Store/Play store etc.

what am I missing?  I've searched the terms deploy / install / package but have come up with nothing bar these 3rd party tools, at the moment it is only a home development piece, so don't really want to release to a store to see it working on my phone, I have offline features hence I need it installed rather than a web page style app.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "install a Html 5 web app on a phone" ?

Comment: so that it can run offline, HTML has offline capabilities that would be no good as a webpage, as you wouldn't be able to access it? Like I say my terminology could be wrong but it would have to exist locally on the phone to work without internet? surely?...   Of course maybe you can't this is sort of my question?

Comment: I haven't understand what you want exactly. If you want to build an app that  works without internet you can do it by native code (Android), or by Html5+javascript (cross-platform)

Comment: It needs to be cross-platform hence I am doing it HTML 5, but how do I get the app onto my phone?

Comment: There is a 3rd possibility: integrate html5 files inside WebView(it's an Android native component).
In all cases you need to develop an app (phone app). 
For more info about cross-platform: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3369413/developing-cross-platform-mobile-application
 And an e.g of using a WebView: http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-webview-example/