# How to start learning mobile development?

Tags: cordova, mobile

I want to know from where should I begin with learning mobile devlopment using phonegap or development for mobile websites. For eg. I was looking to know how can I call a phone number and I found that using "tel:" protocol in anchor tag will call the phone number. Now, I went through the phonegap's doc and I did not find it there.

So, from where should I begin? I am confused. I am not able to find a starting point.

Answer (score 1):

Its based upon your target. Look at here, [mobile platform for mobile development.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414288/j2me-vs-android-vs-iphone-vs-symbian-vs-windows-ce) See this wiki article, [Mobile application development.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_application_development) Also see this discussion, [Overview of cross platform mobile development.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219839/quick-overview-of-cross-platform-mobile-development)

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for. To all those who closed this and marked down - learn from Bharath. He helped me get started. If you guys thought that it was vague I could have rectified it and asked more clearly. I just wanted to know from where I should start.